# How to check enabled features for Qt build?

Tags: qt, vulkan

I want to use `Qt 5.10.1` with `Vulkan`. I downloaded prebuilt `gcc_64` version, opened `hellowulkanwindow` application, set `VULKAN_SDK` in build environment. But the compilation gives me a lot of errors, for example `'QVulkanWindow' does not name a type`. It looks like the macro `QT_CONFIG(vulkan)` return false, but I'm pretty sure that prebuilt version should come with `Vulkan` enabled.

`VulkanSDK` installed on my system, I can run demos. Also I can run non-qt code which uses `Vulkan`.

So how to check that feature `QT_FEATURE_vulkan` is enabled?

Upd: I ran `configure -list-features` in 5.10.1 sources and it didn't showed me anything related to `Vulkan`.

Comment: Try `#if QT_HAS_FEATURE(vulkan) // code for vulkan #endif `.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand how to use it, why? In my case `QT_HAS_FEATURE` defined as `#  define QT_HAS_FEATURE(x)             0` because `__has_feature` not defined. What does that means?

Comment: if defined then or ifdef or the answer below. I was answering from my past experiences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the `QT_FEATURE_vulkan` definition in the `qtgui-config.h` header file (1 means enabled, -1 means disabled). You can just type `QT_FEATURE_vulkan` in Qt Creator and press <kbd>F2</kbd> to nagivate to its location in the header file.

Apparently Qt 5.10.0 and 5.10.1 provided by the official installer do not have Vulkan support enabled, at least on Linux.

Comment: Thank you. You're right, for Linux build `QT_FEATURE_vulkan` is `-1`. After building it from the sources it is `QT_FEATURE_vulkan 1`.